# Is it allowed to use the opposite of a word in The $100,000 Pyramid?

Tags: game-show, the-100000-pyramid

For the 7th question, for them to win $10,000, the answer was "happy places". She described places like Disney World and amusement parks, and then even the host came over and asked relaxing experiences. And the gentleman didn't know what it was.

Meanwhile, I and my wife are screaming, saying "not bad day", "not bad (things like that)".

Would you be allowed in this game to say the opposite of a word or anything like that? My assumption is that if the question was "happy places," I would immediately say "sad" or try to express the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

**No, of course you can't just say antonyms**.

[ABC's own website is pretty useless](https://abc.com/shows/the-100000-pyramid), not providing an official list of rules for some reason but—[at least according to the net](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/25054/tv-rules-winners-circle)—key rules for the last round are

- No direct synonyms
- No hand gestures, to keep the focus on the words
- No prepositional phrases for some reason
- Nothing too overly long, not that you have much time

It's the last one you'd be running afoul of. ***Not bad-day* is just a synonym of *Happy day***. *Sad day* + an agreement that your partner puts 'not' in front of anything would work the same way. You could start listing *examples* of the opposite of your topic, I suppose: *I was arrested*, *My wife left*, *My dog left*, *My mom was hit by a car*, *I lost my job*... with the other person knowing they're supposed to Bizarro World/Opposite Day everything. At that point you're just playing the game normally but adding an extra layer of difficulty for yourself and confusion/interest for the folks at home. Possibly good TV but not actually any more efficient.

[You're welcome to try to prove me wrong about that, though](https://www.castingpyramid.com/apply/).